# python, color dataframe value based on row and column condition

Tags: python, pandas

There is a sale plan as in the table, can i ask how to color table values based on the column (hour) and row (sale_hours). if a column in within the sale_hour, color the value in yellow.

[image]

| `item` | `sale_hours` | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `item1` | `[1-2]` | 0.3 | **0.3** | **0.3** | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| `item2` | `[11-2]` | **0.4** | **0.5** | **0.4** | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | **0.4** | **0.5** |
| `item3` | `[6-7][10-1]` | **0.2** | **0.2** | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | **0.1** | **0.2** | 0.2 | 0.2 | **0.2** | **0.2** | **0.2** |

I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Please don’t publish a DLF as picture, how should we use this? Share a minimal working example and you expected output. Where is the column hours?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use pandas [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) the sale hour-ranges, then flag the cells with a column name (*i.e an hour*) that [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) those ranges and finally call the [*Styler*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) to format the corresponding cells :

```
import re
from itertools import chain

FIRST_HOUR, LAST_HOUR = 0, 12
def make_ranges(range_like):
    init_ranges = [
        (int(s), int(e))
        for s, e in re.findall(r"\[(\d+)-(\d+)\]", range_like)
    ]
    sale_ranges = []
    for s, e in init_ranges:
        if s > e:
            sale_ranges.extend(
                chain(*map(range, (s, FIRST_HOUR), (LAST_HOUR + 1, e + 1)))
            )
        else:
            sale_ranges.extend(range(s, e + 1))
    return sale_ranges

ranges = df["sale_hours"].apply(make_ranges)
def highlight_onlyif(ser, color="yellow"):
  return [
      f"background-color:{color}" if check else ""
      for check in ser.index.isin(ranges.loc[ser.name])
  ]

out = (
    df.style.apply(
        highlight_onlyif,
        subset=df.columns.difference(["item", "sale_hours"]),
        axis=1).format(precision=1)
)

# out.to_excel("file.xlsx", index=False) # uncomment to make a new spreadsheet
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: **NB** : This assumes `df = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx")` (*or any equivalent*).

Comment: that's brilliant! great!